# Sort enum column based on language

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say I have the following simple setup:

```
public enum Status
{
    Pending  = 0,
    Accepted = 1,
    Rejected = 2
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

...and I desire the following ascending sorting for `Status` for two different languages:

```
Language 1: 1, 0, 2
Language 2: 0, 1, 2
```

Is there a simple way to do this in entity framework? I feel like this is probably a common scenario.

I'm thinking the only way is to maintain a separate table with all the translations for Status... then sort by the name column in that table based on the users current language. I wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a query without having a separate table, but it's not pretty. Nor is it very flexible. Since EF relies on well known methods to map to the equivalent SQL function, you can't interject custom functions. However, you can manually set the order using a `let`:

```
var query = from e in MyEntity
            let sortOrder = UserLanguage == Language1 // Handle Language 1 Sort
                                ? e.Status == Pending 
                                      ? 1 : e.Status == Accepted ? 0 : 2
                           : e.Status == Pending // Handle Language 2 sort
                               ? 0 : e.Status == Accepted ? 1 : 2                                                                
            orderby sortOrder
            select e
```

And this is only for two language. Another way I could think of is to write the expression tree yourself. This would have the advantage that you can split the logic for each language. We can extract the ternary condition logic and place them in an extension static class. Here's a sample of what it could look like:

```
public static class QuerySortExtension
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<MyEntity, int>>> _orderingMap;
    private static readonly Expression<Func<MyEntity, int>> _defaultSort;

    public static IOrderedQueryable<MyEntity> LanguageSort(this IQueryable<MyEntity> query, string language)
    {
        Expression<Func<MyEntity, int>> sortExpression;
        if (!_orderingMap.TryGetValue(language, out sortExpression))
            sortExpression = _defaultSort;

        return query.OrderBy(sortExpression);
    }

    static QuerySortExtension()
    {
        _orderingMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<MyEntity, int>>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
            { "EN", e => e.Status == Status.Pending ? 1 : e.Status == Status.Accepted ? 0 : 2 },
            { "JP", e => e.Status == Status.Pending ? 2 : e.Status == Status.Accepted ? 1 : 0 }
        };

        // Default ordering
        _defaultSort = e => (int)e.Status;
    }

}
```

And you can use the following method this way:

```
var entities = new[] { 
    new MyEntity { Status = Status.Accepted }, 
    new MyEntity { Status = Status.Pending }, 
    new MyEntity { Status = Status.Rejected } 
}.AsQueryable();

var query = from e in entities.LanguageSort("EN")
            select e;
var queryJp = from e in entities.LanguageSort("JP")
              select e;

Console.WriteLine("Sorting with EN");
foreach (var e in query)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Status);

Console.WriteLine("Sorting with JP");
foreach (var e in queryJp)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Status);
```

Which output the following:

```
Sorting with EN
Accepted
Pending
Rejected
Sorting with JP
Rejected
Accepted
Pending
```

Answer (score 2):

EF will sort based on the type of DB column you have mapped the enum to (presumably an int), so it will sort the same way it sorts ints.

IF you want some kind of custom sorter you will have to write your own and sort in memory.

Not really sure i understand your separate table concept, could you give more details.

Comment: Ben, I've outlined the table idea in a [separate answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22332983/188246).

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Simon's answer since it was an alternative to what I mentioned in the question. Here's a way I figured out how to do it with a separate table that works. Obvious downside is that you have to maintain translations in the database...

```
public enum Status
{
    Pending  = 0,
    Accepted = 1,
    Rejected = 2
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int    MyEntityID { get; set; }
    public Status Status     { get; set; }
}

public enum Language
{
    Language1 = 0,
    Language2 = 1
}

public class StatusTranslation
{
    public int      StatusTranslationID { get; set; }
    public Language Language            { get; set; }
    public Status   Status              { get; set; }
    public string   Name                { get; set; }
}
```

Insert all the translations into the SQL table in whatever way:

```
INSERT INTO StatusTranslations (Language, Status, Name) VALUES (0, 0, "Pending")
// etc...
INSERT INTO StatusTranslations (Language, Status, Name) VALUES (1, 0, "En attendant")
// etc...
```

Now join and sort:

```
var userLanguage = Language.Language1;
var results = db.MyEntities.Join(
                  db.StatusTranslations, 
                  e => e.Status, 
                  s => s.Status, 
                  (e, s) => new { MyEntity = e, Status = s }
            )
            .Where(e => e.Status.Language == userLanguage)
            .Select(e => new {
                 MyEntityID = e.MyEntity.MyEntityID
                 StatusName = e.Status.Name
            }).OrderBy(e => e.StatusName).ToList();
```

I never compiled this example code (only my own code) so I apologise for any mistakes, but it should give the idea well enough.

Comment: I am drawn more to Simon's expression based solution.  Yours results in list of anonymous types which is less flexible than Simon's which returns and OrderedQueryable of your actual entity. Its much more readable and easy to understand so therefor maintain.  The last reason may or may not be a disadvantage, it doesn't require a new table which is good, but the mapping is in code so adding a new language requires a code change.  Unless you really need the flexibility of storing the language map in the DB then I would say the the first two advantages of Simon's solution outweigh yours.

Comment: Ben, thanks for your input! The example uses anonymous types for brevity. In my actual code I'm creating new instances of a defined class (I'm not a fan of anonymous types either). To return an OrderedQueryable you just need to leave off the `.ToList()`. In my case, the company I'm working at has been using Translation tables in stored procedures for displaying in an ASP.NET gridview... so introducing a new table isn't that big of a deal. Anyways, if it were my own project I'd be draw to use Simon's solution in order to not have translations in the database.